# Unpublish item using Powershell

Tags: 2013-sp1, powershell

I have been working with a PowerShell script to publish things, and it has worked perfectly.

I am now trying to extend it to be able to unpublish items as well, but have not found the right command or the right set of parameters.

The error that I get is:

```
Cannot find an overload for "Publish" and the argument count: "5".
```

My code is:

```
$publishIntructionData = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.PublishInstructionData
$publishIntructionData.RenderInstruction = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.RenderInstructionData 
if ($jobPublishAction -eq "unpublish")
{
    $publishIntructionData = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.UnPublishInstructionData
}
$publishIntructionData.ResolveInstruction = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ResolveInstructionData 
$publishIntructionData.ResolveInstruction.IncludeChildPublications = $allPublications
if ($jobPublushAction -eq "publish")
{
    $publishIntructionData.ResolveInstruction.IncludeWorkflow = $true
}
if ($jobPublishAction -eq "unpublish")
{
    # $publishIntructionData.ResolveInstruction.ResolvePurpose = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.ResolvePurpose.UnPublish
    # Unpublish = 1
    $publishIntructionData.ResolveInstruction.Purpose = 1
}

if ($scheduled -eq $true) {
    $publishIntructionData.StartAt = $scheduledDateTime
}

$result = $client.Publish($Id, $publishIntructionData, $publicationTarget, $priority, $readOptions)
```

Comment: You have a typo... $jobPublushAction..

Comment: My personal preference is not to use a "magic number" for something like ResolveInstruction.Purpose. You can either simply say "Publish", or if you are addicted to intellisense [Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ResolvePurpose]::Publish - by the time you get to the ::, you will be able to see the valid options

Answer (score 5):

I had to create a new object. `$publishInstructionData` retained the object type of `PublishInstructionData` even though I re-initialized it.

The changes to the code include:

```
# Create a different object altogether
$unpublishIntructionData = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.UnPublishInstructionData
$unpublishIntructionData.ResolveInstruction = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ResolveInstructionData 
$unpublishIntructionData.ResolveInstruction.IncludeWorkflow = $true
# Call a different method
$result = $client.UnPublish($Id, $unpublishIntructionData, $publicationTarget, $priority, $readOptions)
```

Comment: It's hard to believe that a variable retains it value if you re-initialize it. I guess the only real issue was that you should use a different method for un-publishing.

Comment: I think the type of the variable was retained - I guess because powershell is weirdly typed (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115643/is-powershell-a-strongly-typed-language)

Answer (score 5):

If you'd excuse the shameless plug, I recommend that you start using the open-source [Tridion PowerShell Modules](https://github.com/pkjaer/tridion-powershell-modules) that I maintain.

With the Tridion-CoreService module imported, you could just do this:

```
Unpublish-TridionItem -Id $Id -Target $publicationTarget -Priority $priority;
```

And similar for Publish-TridionItem. There is already a decent amount of features available, with more to come. If something is missing from the modules, I take pull requests :) Or you could just ask for it and I will try to add it as soon as possible.

If everybody used and contributed to that project, over time we'd build a comprehensive library of functionality that benefits everyone who needs/wants to work with SDL Web from within PowerShell.